# How to make a FloatingActionButton work on top of a ListView and position it correctly

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, floating-action-button

I am trying to get a `SuaveControls.FloatingActionButton` to work on top of a ListView following the example on this page - https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-create-a-floating-action-button/

My `ListView` is inside a `StackLayout` so I decided to wrap them into an `AbsoluteLayout`

Here is the View/XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SuaveControls.Views;assembly=SuaveControls.FloatingActionButton"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DPM.XForms"
             x:Class="DPM.XForms.ProjectListPage" 
             Title="Drive Plus Mobile"
             >
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="1">

            <Label Text="TopBar             ..." BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <!-- Project Search/Filter toolbar-->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="7" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Label Text="Projects " TextColor="DarkGray" Font="Bold,17" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="0">
                    <Button Image="Search.png" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27"></Button>
                    <Button Image="LeftBS.png" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27"></Button>
                    <Button Image="CenteredBS.png" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27"></Button>
                    <Button Text="++" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27" Clicked="CreateProject_Clicked"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Pin projects" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="25" />



            <ListView x:Name="lvProjects" ItemTapped="OnProjectTapped" RowHeight="54" BackgroundColor="DarkGray">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <!-- Project Row -->
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0,1,0,1" >
                                <Button 
                                Image="Colombia.png" 
                                BackgroundColor="White" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                WidthRequest="54"
                                HeightRequest="54"
                                >
                                </Button>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    Font="Bold,17"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                />
                                    <Label 
                                   Text="{Binding Brand}" 
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                />
                                    <Label 
                                   Text=".." 
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   VerticalOptions="End" 
                                />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Button Text="3"  WidthRequest="44"></Button>
                                <Button Text=">"  WidthRequest="44" BackgroundColor="White" ></Button>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
        <views:FloatingActionButton 
            Image="CreateProject.png" 

            WidthRequest="80" 
            HeightRequest="80" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Clicked="FloatingActionButton_Clicked"
            >

        </views:FloatingActionButton>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

But with this approach two things are happening

1. When the device is in Landscape mode the `ListView` is not growing as it did before adding the `AbsoluteLayout`

[image: Horizontal Layout Fails]

2. Dont know how to position the `FloatingActionButton` to always stay on the lower right corner of any device

[image: FAB position]

I have also tried placing the `FloatingActionButton` inside the current StackLayout but it does not float is just added below or above the listview as a regular "row" like is shown here

[image]

Feel free to use the comments if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Swift_Talt answer and this discussion- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52420/create-a-layered-page-layering-controls

I found this solution using a Grid of one (1) cell where the ListView (background) and the FloatingActionButton are on the same unique cell

This is how it looks:

[image]

[image]

And here is the View/Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SuaveControls.Views;assembly=SuaveControls.FloatingActionButton"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DPM.XForms"
             x:Class="DPM.XForms.ProjectListPage" 
             Title="Drive Plus Mobile"
             >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="1">

            <Label Text="TopBar             ..." BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <!-- Project Search/Filter toolbar-->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="7" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Label Text="Projects " TextColor="DarkGray" Font="Bold,17" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="0">
                    <Button Image="Search.png" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27"></Button>
                    <Button Image="LeftBS.png" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27"></Button>
                    <Button Image="CenteredBS.png" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27"></Button>
                    <Button Text="++" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27" Clicked="CreateProject_Clicked"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Pin projects" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="25" />



            <ListView x:Name="lvProjects" ItemTapped="OnProjectTapped" RowHeight="54" BackgroundColor="DarkGray">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <!-- Project Row -->
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0,1,0,1" >
                                <Button 
                                Image="Colombia.png" 
                                BackgroundColor="White" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                WidthRequest="54"
                                HeightRequest="54"
                                >
                                </Button>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    Font="Bold,17"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                />
                                    <Label 
                                   Text="{Binding Brand}" 
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                />
                                    <Label 
                                   Text=".." 
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   VerticalOptions="End" 
                                />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Button Text="3"  WidthRequest="44"></Button>
                                <Button Text=">"  WidthRequest="44" BackgroundColor="White" ></Button>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" Spacing="0" Margin="15">
            <views:FloatingActionButton 
            Image="CreateProject.png" 

            WidthRequest="80" 
            HeightRequest="80" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Clicked="FloatingActionButton_Clicked"
            >

            </views:FloatingActionButton>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove absolute layout since you can see that your layout doesn't fully expand at landscape mode.

You can try this one

```
<MainLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    //YourTopBar
   // YourListView

  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="End"
               VerticalOptions="End"
               Spacing="0"
               Margin="15">
       <YourFloatingButton />

  </StackLayout>
</MainLayout>
```

The mainlayout can be a grid or stacklayout

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this produces something very similar to the third image of my question, but with the button to the right and bottom but is not floating

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the layout to use Grid and AbsoluteLayout to wrapper the listview and Floating button. So it is somethig like the following:(As I don't have your list datasource, to be simple, I just put a mock list)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SuaveControls.Views;assembly=SuaveControls.FloatingActionButton"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App51"
             x:Class="App51.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <!-- Project Search/Filter toolbar-->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="7" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Label Text="Projects " TextColor="DarkGray" Font="Bold,17" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="0">
                    <Button Image="Search.png" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27"></Button>
                    <Button Image="LeftBS.png" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27"></Button>
                    <Button Image="CenteredBS.png" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27"></Button>
                    <Button Text="++" WidthRequest="27" HeightRequest="27" ></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Pin projects" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="25" />
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="FAB" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="LightGray"
               TextColor="CadetBlue" />
            <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <ListView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorColor="Black"
                      RowHeight="50"
                      BackgroundColor="Gray">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <!-- Project Row -->
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0,1,0,1" >
                                    <Button 
                                Image="Colombia.png" 
                                BackgroundColor="White" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                WidthRequest="54"
                                HeightRequest="54"
                                >
                                    </Button>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                        <Label 
                                    Text="Binding Name" 
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    Font="Bold,17"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                />
                                        <Label 
                                   Text="Binding Name" 
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                />
                                        <Label 
                                   Text=".." 
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   VerticalOptions="End" 
                                />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <Button Text="3"  WidthRequest="44"></Button>
                                    <Button Text=">"  WidthRequest="44" BackgroundColor="White" ></Button>

                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <views:FloatingActionButton  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                    Image="CreateProject.png" 
                    WidthRequest="80" 
                    HeightRequest="80" 
                    HorizontalOptions="End" 
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.0,1.0,-1,-1"
                                                Margin="10" >
                </views:FloatingActionButton>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </Grid>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And the result is like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: using this approach makes the "Floating" button appear as the last row below the ListView and therefore is not floating, see third image of my question

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the disappearance of the "Floating", I have modified the answer.